# Regex Notepad ++: How to remove everything except url?

Tags: regex, url, notepad++, sitemap

I have sitemap like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
    <loc>http://mywebsite.com/article1</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-08-10</lastmod>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://mywebsite.com/article2</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-08-10</lastmod>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://mywebsite.com/article3</loc>
    <lastmod>2014-08-10</lastmod>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

I only want to keep url which inside . Do you know way to match the others and replace by nothing ? Thank you very much !

Comment: @aduch, Hello, I am using Notepad ++

Comment: @Loong Notepad++ is the name of the program you are using, what is the name of the language?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481078/how-to-perform-negative-search-or-replace-in-common-text-editors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your desired result is like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/article1
http://mywebsite.com/article2
http://mywebsite.com/article3
```

search for:

```
\h*<url\b.*?(http[^<]+).*?</url>|<.*?>\s*
```

and replace with captured url (captured in first parenthesized group)

```
\1
```

`\h` matches any horzintal space, `[^<]+` matches one or more characters, that are not `<`

Be sure to check the checkbox `. matches \r and \n`

Also see [example and explanation on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oX8cV3/4)

Comment: Thank you for perfect regex and great explanation ! However, I edited something my post. Can you help me edit the regex, please ?

Comment: @Loong See update or just do a 2nd replace: Remaining `<.*?>\s*` with empty.

Comment: Hello, it worked like a charm when I try with notepad ++. However, when I use Find in Files to process multiple file, it doesn't work. Do you know why ?

Comment: @Loong Did you check `. matches \r and \n` / same options? Else I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you intend to match what's inside  elements. A multi-line regex matching  content could do the job: (http.*)

Comment: No, i want to keep URL, not remove it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to match everythin except the URLs and replace with nothing:

```
.*<url>.*\n?.*<loc>|<\/loc>(.*\n?){4}<\/url>
```